# Isabelle/HOL with HOL-Z and ZETA

Tags: isabelle, z-notation

I have seen some papers that describe how to use the Z notation with Isabelle/HOL using the tools HOL-Z and ZETA. I was not able to find these tools, have they ever been published? Are there other ways to use Isabelle with the Z notation?

Comment: Never heard of those. Can you provide a link to a paper? Maybe contact the authors of the papers directly?

Comment: Here is one:   
[HOL-Z 2.0: A Proof Environment for Z-Specifications](http://www.jucs.org/doi?doi=10.3217/jucs-009-02-0152)

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to substitute Isabelle/HOL for one of the [HOL theorem provers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOL_(proof_assistant)) (which also adopt the LCF approach to soundness) then you should consider [ProofPower](http://www.lemma-one.com/ProofPower/index/index.html), which also embeds the Z notation in HOL.  ProofPower-Z has been used on large industrial examples for many years, in particular to discharge verification conditions to show the correctness of Ada source code.

Comment: I have heard of ProofPower and had a look into it. It uses a markup language with special characters but I would prefer a pure ASCII markup, ideally solely based on LaTeX.

Comment: Whether you tell ProofPower to work with UTF-8 or its own bespoke character encoding, you can always write ASCII mark up with %...% sequences.  These have some similarity to the LaTeX sequences - the mapping can be found in the file <pp-install-dir>/etc/sievekeyword.  Note that these escapes can be used in ML names too, which makes PPML different from SML.  Personally, I find the Unicode characters much more readable.  Consider ⓩ∀ x : ℤ ⦁ 0 ≤ x⌝ vs. %SZT%%forall% x : %bbZ% %spot% 0 %leq% x%>%.

Comment: Well thank you for the hint. I am used to something like \begin{szt}\forall x : \num @ 0 \leq x \end{szt}. Maybe I could define some macros and preprocess before calling the ProofPower tools.